# Possible compiler bug: Weird results using boost bessel functions with Intel compiler between two machines?

Tags: c++, linux, boost, intel

I'm trying to use boost's bessel function (cyl_bessel_j) in a project. However, I'm finding that the function is returning results with an incorrect sign after around 2000 calls to it.

I've tested this between two machines, one is a CentOS 5.8 (Final) machine, where it oddly enough works, and a RHEL 6.3 (Santiago) machine where it fails.

Both machines are using Boost 1.50.0, and the 13.1.3 20130607 Intel compiler. The CentOS machine is using gcc 4.1.2 20080704, and the RHEL machine is using gcc 4.4.6 20120305.

Here is my code:

```
template<typename FloatType> FloatType funcT(FloatType z, FloatType phi,
                                             int n, int m, int p)
{
  using namespace boost::math;
  FloatType sqrt2PiZ = sqrt((2 * M_PI)/z);
  FloatType nrmLeg = normalizedLegendre(n,m,-sin(phi));
  FloatType besselJ = cyl_bessel_j(p + 0.5, z);

  std::cout << "  " << p << "," << z << "  besselJ: " << besselJ << std::endl;

  return sqrt2PiZ * nrmLeg * besselJ;
}
```

Running on the two machines, I found the only term that was coming out different between the two was the besselJ term. For the first 1980 calls to the function, they return identical results, however, on the 1981st call, the RHEL machine suddenly switches sign in its results. The first few failed terms print out as follows (RHEL SIDE):

```
  ...
  1,7.90559 besselJ: -0.0504874
  2,7.90559 besselJ: 0.264237
  3,7.90559 besselJ: 0.217608
  ...
```

Running a reference test in MATLAB using the besselJ function, I find that for these inputs, the signs should be reversed, and indeed the CentOS machine agrees with MATLAB.

I decided to write a simple hello-world style example with the besselJ function to try and determine the cause of the failure:

```
#include <boost/math/special_functions/bessel.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  double besselTerm = boost::math::cyl_bessel_j(1.5, 7.90559);
  std::cout << besselTerm << std::endl;
}
```

This test returns the expected value of 0.0504874 on **BOTH** machines.

At this point, I'm ripping my hair out trying to determine the cause of the problem. It seems to be some weird compiler bug or stack corruption.But then, how can stack corruption give the exact correct answer with the exception of a single bit?

Has anyone run into an issue like this with boost or the Intel compiler in general?

**Additional info:**
It has been found that the minimal case test breaks on GCC 4.4.6 with the --fast-math flag. I was also able to get the minimal test case to fail with the Intel compiler by using the -std=c++11 flag (which is what the larger project uses).

Comment: Are those inputs to `boost::math::cyl_bessel_j` really the same?  Or do they differ towards the LSB and those digits just aren't getting printed.

Comment: They are the same. If they weren't, the sqrt2PiZ term would be different between the two machines, and I've verified that term is identical.

Comment: It seems like they differ even between the printout `1,7.90559 besselJ: -0.0504874` and the minimal example `cyl_bessel_j(1.5, 7.90559)`.

Comment: Now that is weird. How did you run your test? My minimal example gives a positive sign on both machines.

Comment: No, sorry -- just refer to your question above.  In one print out it would appear that the inputs are **`1`** and `7.90559`.  In the minimal code it would appear that the inputs are **`1.5`** and `7.90559`

Comment: Interesting.  I get different results based on the presence/absence of `--fast-math` (differing only in sign).  `4.8.1-10ubuntu9`.  Maybe it is a bug.  My guess is that this might not be minimal enough for a bug report.  See if you can tell where it goes wrong inside of `cyl_bessel_j`.

Comment: I just repeated the behavior you described using gcc and --fast-math with GCC 4.4.6, but not 4.1.2 (4.1.2's behavior is correct).

The intel compiler doesn't support the --fast-math option, so I'm looking at my project's make files to determine what it's doing different than the minimal case test (which I was compiling by hand).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bug was submitted to the boost library trac system.

It was found, however, that the problem is in the std c++ libraries and indicates an issue in GCC 4.4.7.

Boost devs created a workaround patch that addresses the issue at:
https://github.com/boostorg/math/commit/9f8ffee4b7a3f82b1c582735d43522d7d0cde746